# How to make PageTitleStrip for iOS?

Tags: ios

I am create a `ScrollView`. on this Scrollview i am adding 4 `UiView` ans scroll that one .

My code is like this :

```
// Set the scroll ContentSize & ContentOffset

[scroll setContentOffset:CGPointMake(320, 0)];
[scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320 * 4, 420)];

[View1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 420)];
[View2 setFrame:CGRectMake(320, 0, 320, 420)];
[View3 setFrame:CGRectMake(320 * 2, 0, 320, 420)];
[View4 setFrame:CGRectMake(320 * 3, 0, 320, 420)];
```

I am doing like this. But this is not perfect way. I want how can i make perfect `PageTitleStripe`. Suppose when user scroll the page that time top name bar also moving according to scroll. Like: ***Google Play store***

[image: This is my requirement. there is a purple color bar. my requirement is when i scroll the view that time that purple color bar will be move according to scroll]

Comment: Maybe show a screenshot of what you have and what you want

Comment: I add the screenshot . please help me

Comment: Could you solve this problem?